# Returning Data from function into a Global Variable (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to return result and be able to access result array from this function. Everything is working in the function, however I cannot return anything or access results or any variable created inside the function from outside the closure. I want to access result.valueForKey("id") from outside the closure (inside the ViewDidLoad). How can I do that? (Please see the "This works" and "This doesn't work" parts..

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

 var facebookid: NSString = ""
 var username: NSString = ""
 var userEmail:NSString = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
{
    let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    self.view.addSubview(loginView)
    loginView.center = self.view.center
    loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile"]
    loginView.delegate = self

} else {

    returnUserData()

    println("test") // This works (gets printed)
    println(facebookid)  // This doesn't work (not even nil)
    println(self.username) // This doesn't work either (not even nil)

  }
}



func returnUserData()
{

let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
    else
    {

        self.facebookid = result.valueForKey("id") as NSString!
        self.username = result.valueForKey("name") as NSString!
        self.userEmail = result.valueForKey("email") as NSString!
        println(result) // This works
        println(facebookid) // This works


    }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your request in `returnUserData` is not a synchronized function, so it updates your datas after you call println() on those datas. You should read more about MultiThreading in iOS.

```
returnUserData()  //it calls returnUserData() to update your facebookid & self.username. However, in `returnUserData`, it use `FBSDKGraphRequest` to get facebook datas. As FBSDKGraphRequest retrieve datas from internet connection (and it takes time to finish), it is designed to retrieve datas in async, to avoid blocking your function.

//So, you risk to finish your returnUserData function before the process of FBSDKGraphRequest is terminated (and the completionHandler is called to update your data). 

println("test") // This works (gets printed)
println(facebookid)  // This doesn't work (not even nil) //this is called before your completionHandler is invoked, you don't have new data
println(self.username) // This doesn't work either (not even nil) //this is called before your completionHandler is invoked too, you don't have new data.
```

To fixe that problem, you should do your work on new value of `facebookid` and `self.username` in the `completionHandler` block

Comment: I did a lot of reading on MultiThreading and figured out the problem. In fact, whatever I've tried didn't give me any luck on success. Do you have any idea how to get around in my case?